# Linux bash or sed command to increment a version number

Tags: bash, sed

I need something in a script to increment a version number: when I have the string `1.0.2`, I want to have a bash command that makes it `1.0.3`.

Something like this but this doesnt work:

```
CI_COMMIT_TAG=1.0.2
patch=$((CI_COMMIT_TAG + 1)); echo new path=${CI_COMMIT_TAG}
```

gives this error:

```
1.0.2: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0.2")
```

Probably because `1.0.2` is a string and not a number.

How to solve this ?

Comment: `bash` has no native support for floats.

Comment: What comes after `1.0.9` - `1.0.10` or `1.2.0` or something else? Is there ever a point where the second (or first) digit gets incremented?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(imo) The easiest approach would be to split the version number into separate (integer) components, do the math, and then paste back together into the desired version string.

At this point there are several ways to approach this idea.

One idea using some basic commands to implement each of the proposed steps:

```
CI_COMMIT_TAG=1.0.2
IFS=. read -r v1 v2 v3 <<< "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"    # split into (integer) components
((v3++))                                         # do the math
patch="${v1}.${v2}.${v3}"                        # paste back together
```

This generates:

```
$ echo "${patch}"
1.0.3
```

By splitting into the separate (integer) components it'll also be easier if/when you want to increment the first/second component.

---

---

Another approach where we let `awk` do all the work:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="."}                    # define input/output field delimiter as "."
      {$3++                           # increment field #3 "+1" (think "inplace" increment of field #3)
       print                          # print current line
      }
' <<< "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
1.0.3

# removing comments, collapsing to a one-liner, and storing the result in variable 'patch'

$ patch=$(awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="."} {$3++; print}' <<< "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}")
$ echo $patch
1.0.3
```

---

---

**NOTE**: Both of these solutions assume the 3rd component is an integer otherwise the step of adding '+1' (`v3++` / `$3++`) will fail; additional coding could be added to validate the 3rd component is in fact an integer.

Comment: +2 if I could; very accurate and instructive answer

Comment: In the `awk` command, replace `$3++` with `if ($NF ~ /^[0-9]+$/) $NF++` to cope with other than 3 components, and skip non-numerics.

Comment: Great first solution fits for me. Thank you markp-fuso

Comment: I have studied also the second awk solution and the more generic solution which Gordon suggests and maybe thats even better. Thanks Gordon.

Comment: Note that you could do: `patch="${v1}.${v2}.$((++v3))"`, although  that's merely a stylistic choice and it is not unreasonable to avoid code like this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use bash array with the same note from @markp-fuso

```
CI_COMMIT_TAG=1.0.2
patch=(${CI_COMMIT_TAG//./ })
patch[2]="$((${patch[2]}+1))"
patch="${patch[*]}"
patch="${patch// /.}"
echo "$patch"
```

Answer (score 0):

## `sed` + `bash` versioning system

You asked for a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) **or** [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) solution, here is a full [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) **plus** [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) versionning script.

Script will retrieve and parse current version number, increment them regarding command line options (subversion, minor or major) and build a `sed` command line for editing file in place.

### Preamble: version line format.

At begin of my script, I will find a line in this format:

> ```
> # Version: xx.xx.xx -- Last update: Thu Mar 30 09:23:04 2023
> ```

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) `printf`, I could build this line by something like:

```
LANG=C printf '# Version: %d.%d.%d -- Last update: %(%c)T' $maj $min $sub -1
```

If not found in first comment lines, this script will **add** a version line.

### Usage:

Using `getopts`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Version: 0.0.1 -- Last update: Thu Mar 30 08:28:55 2023

progname=${0##*/} oper=sub testmode=false
uniqFlagMsg='Flags -m and -M are mutually exclusive.'
usage() {
    cat <<eoUsage
$pro        gname [-M|-m] [-h]
    -h  Show this.
    -M  For Major update
    -m  For Minor update
    -t  Test mode: Don't do anything, but show what would be done.
$uniqFlagMsg
eoUsage
}
die() { echo >&2 "ERROR $progname: $*";exit 1;}
while getopts 'mMth' opt;do case $opt in
    h) usage;exit 0;;
    m) [[ $oper == maj ]] && die "$uniqFlagMsg";oper=min;;
    M) [[ $oper == min ]] && die "$uniqFlagMsg";oper=maj;;
    t) testmode=true;;
    *) die "Unknown option '$opt'."
esac;done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
file="$1"
[ -f "$file" ] || die "File '$file' not found."
```

### Reading file header for retrieving current version number

```bash
maj=0 min=0 sub=0 found=false
while IFS=:- read leftpart middle _;do
    case $leftpart in
        \#\ Version )
            middle=(${middle//./ }) found=true
            maj=${middle[0]} min=${middle[1]} sub=${middle[2]}
            ;;
        \#* ) ;;
        * ) break;;
    esac
done <"$file"
printf -v oldver %d.%d.%d $maj $min $sub
case $oper in
    sub ) ((sub++));;
    min ) ((min++));sub=0;;
    maj ) ((maj++));min=0 sub=0;;
esac
TZ=UTC LANG=C printf -v newstring \
    '# Version: %.0f.%.0f.%.0f -- Last update: %(%c)T' $maj $min $sub -1

if $found; then
    sedcmd="s/^# Version: .* -- Last update: .*/$newstring/"
else
    sedcmd="2i $newstring"
fi
if $testmode; then
    printf 'sed -e "%s" -i.%s "%s"\n' "$sedcmd" $oldver "$file"
else
    sed -e "$sedcmd" -i.$oldver "$file"
fi
```

Then

```bash
./versioning.sh -t versioning.sh
sed -e "s/^# Version: .* -- Last update: .*/# Version: 0.0.2 -- Last update: Thu Mar 30 08:48:13 2023/" -i.0.0.1 "versioning.sh"

./versioning.sh -mt versioning.sh
sed -e "s/^# Version: .* -- Last update: .*/# Version: 0.1.0 -- Last update: Thu Mar 30 08:48:29 2023/" -i.0.0.1 "versioning.sh"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ CI_COMMIT_TAG=1.0.2
$ readarray -td'.' f <<<"$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
$ echo "${f[0]}.${f[1]}.$((f[2]+1))"
1.0.3
```