# Subtracting using Bash

Tags: string, bash, shell

I'm trying to subtract from a decimal number using bash.

For example:
If I have a number 1.0.0.55 I would like to subtract to get to 1.0.0.54.

Here is what I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash

LATEST_RELEASE="myproduct_1.0.0.55"

RELEASE_NUMBER=`echo $LATEST_RELEASE | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g'`

echo $RELEASE_NUMBER

#this only works with whole numbers (i.e. 10055)
PREVIOUS_RELEASE=$(($RELEASE_NUMBER - 1))

echo $PREVIOUS_RELEASE

#EOF
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What should be output for original string `1.0.0.0` ?

Comment: Good question! I wouldn't need that in this scenario. I have a check for for a previous release number, if it doesn't exist I check the date of the file itself to make sure it's older than the current file coming in.

Comment: See also: [Linux bash or sed command to increment a version number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67038121/6136214).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to isolate the part of that string that you want to extract `1` from since you can't subtrack `1` from a string `1.0.0.55`.

Consider using awk here:

```
echo '1.0.0.55' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{$4=$4-1}1'
```

Comment: Maybe better to use `{$NF=$NF-1}` or `{$NF-=1}`

Comment: In total: `echo 1.0.0.55 | awk '{$NF-=1}1' FS=. OFS=.`

Comment: Ok, this works great. I understand the field separator part but I have a quick question about the number of fields part. For the '{$NF-=1}1' , what is the second 1 used for? I could put '{$NF-=1}9' and return the same result. Just curious.

Comment: @Stacker The second `1` after the curly brace is just shorthand in awk. One could write this like: `'{$NF-=1}{print $0}` but since printing the entire line is default behavior you can just pass a "true" condition or `1` and it will cause awk to print. There's a lot of code-golf that we play in awk since it's often used for one-liners like this.

Answer (score 2):

With `bash` and its [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
latest_release="myproduct_1.0.0.55"

first="${latest_release%.*}"

declare -i last                     # set integer flag
last="${latest_release##*.}"-1

previous_release="$first.$last"
echo "$previous_release"
```

Output:

```
myproduct_1.0.0.54
```

Answer (score 1):

`"myproduct_1.0.0.54"` isn't a number, so we can't easily subtract 1 from it.

---

I'd use [Parameter-Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (`${parameter:-word}`)  to get the part after the last `.`, and use that at the number so we can `+ 1`.

Then get everything before the last dot to connect the string again:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

input="myproduct_1.0.0.55"
minus=$((${input##*.} - 1))

echo "${input%.*}.${minus}"
```

Will produce:

```
myproduct_1.0.0.54
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X1lRPykzTz8JyOHiyswrKC2xVcqtLCjKTylNLok31DMAQlNTJa7czLzSYlsVDQ2VarAqZWUtvVoFXQVDTU0urtTkjHwFJaiMqp5WrZ5KNVhDrdL//wA)